# SQL Joining corresponding values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have a table (call it tbl1) that looks like (but with much more rows) :

```
        CUSIP_ID1   CUSIP_ID2   cor        dt_pnts  
        921910709   06738G407   0.99613     252
        739371102   06738G407   0.380706    213
        808524654   06738G407   0.580574    221
        78467V202   06738G407   0.366938    224
        808524854   06738G407   0.0127264   232
        78567V103   06738G407   0.0799898   198
```

etc.

My code is (the second table tbl2 just has an ID# that i use to match values)

```
insert into tbl3 (Ticker, cusip_id, maxcor) 
select b.ID, a.CUSIP_ID1 No_indx_cusip, MAX(abs(a.cor)) maxcor
from  tbl1 a, tbl2 b
where a.CUSIP_ID1 = b.CUSIP_ID
group by a.CUSIP_ID1, b.Ticker
order by maxcor desc
select * from tbl3
```

which returns

```
    Ticker No_Indx_cusip maxcor  dt_pnts
    EDV     921910709   0.99613  NULL
    SCHR    808524854   0.989976 NULL
    VGIT    92206C706   0.988307 NULL
    ELD     97717X867   0.985073 NULL
    PDP     73935X153   0.979131 NULL
    TTFS    00768Y818   0.974691 NULL
    SCHO    808524862   0.974254 NULL
    RLY     78467V103   0.951472 NULL
    PXLG    739371102   0.937278 NULL
    VCIT    92206C870   0.934389 NULL
    INKM    78467V202   0.921616 NULL
    WDTI    97717W125   0.890677 NULL
    CEW     97717W133   0.847838 NULL
```

I would like to select corresponding dt_pnts from tbl1 that match up with the max(abs(a.cor)) value into tbl3 from tbl1 (not working for me for some reason) - i.e. the value of 0.99613 would correspond to dt_pnts value of 252. Thanks!

the result would look like

```
Ticker No_Indx_cusip maxcor  dt_pnts
    EDV     921910709   0.99613  252
    SCHR    808524854   0.989976 124
    VGIT    92206C706   0.988307 252
    ELD     97717X867   0.985073 79
    PDP     73935X153   0.979131 89
    TTFS    00768Y818   0.974691 252
    SCHO    808524862   0.974254 198
    RLY     78467V103   0.951472 38
    PXLG    739371102   0.937278 138
    VCIT    92206C870   0.934389 212
    INKM    78467V202   0.921616 90
    WDTI    97717W125   0.890677 16
    CEW     97717W133   0.847838 153
```

Comment: such a long question for an easy solution i know but just wanted to be clear!

Comment: u havent written a column for dt_pts in your current query and use joins it would help you

Comment: It is a horrible coding practice to use implict joins. Please break this very bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need an additional join on MAX(abs(a.cor)) to the cor value in tbl1 to retrieve the actual dt_pnts for the max cor value.  I think the below will work, as it joins back to your tbl1 table on the CUSIP_ID1 and takes advantage of the HAVING clause to only return the dt_pnts value where the cor value is equal to the MAX(abs(a.cor)) value:

```
select 
    b.ID, a.CUSIP_ID1 No_indx_cusip, MAX(abs(a.cor)) maxcor, dt.dt_pnts
from  
    tbl1 a INNER JOIN
    tbl2 b ON
        a.CUSIP_ID1 = b.CUSIP_ID INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CUSIP_ID1, cor, dt_pnts FROM Table1) dt ON a.CUSIP_ID1 = dt.CUSIP_ID1
WHERE
    a.dt_pnts > 10
group by a.CUSIP_ID1, b.ID, dt.dt_pnts, dt.cor
having dt.cor = MAX(abs(a.cor))
```

Comment: how could i add a condition that would select `max(abs(a.cor))` for `dt_pnts` > 10 ? @cgsmks

Comment: I think you should be able to add a WHERE clause to the (SELECT CUSIP_ID1, cor, dt_pnts FROM Table1) bit, (SELECT CUSIP_ID1, cor, dt_pnts FROM Table1 WHERE dt_pnts > 10)

Comment: that would select 10 out of the 13 results .. i would like to select `max(abs(a.cor))` for `dt_pnts > 10` from the original table (tbl1)... thank you!

Comment: I edited the code above to account for a dt_pnts > 10 condition.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to include the logic for the last column (dt_pts).  Here, I've included the dt_pts column for table3.  Try this, it may work for you.

```
 insert into tbl3 (Ticker, cusip_id, maxcor, dt_pts) 
 select b.ID, a.CUSIP_ID1 No_indx_cusip, MAX(abs(a.cor)) maxcor, a.dt_pts dt_pts
 from  tbl1 a, tbl2 b
 where a.CUSIP_ID1 = b.CUSIP_ID
 group by a.CUSIP_ID1, b.Ticker
 order by maxcor desc
 select * from tbl3
```

Comment: It's generally good practice to include reasoning, in addition to the code.

Comment: Thanks.  We want people to learn from the site, and to be able to apply the answer to their own specific questions.

Comment: Thats why I am here. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: that doesnt give me the corresponding values the 13 dt_pnts that i want (with `max(abs(a.cor))` ) it returns all 1000+ values that i have in my original chart. (`dt_pnts` would also need to be included in the group by clause btw)